# Trouble dynamically changing class instance attributes

Tags: python

I have a `Redshift` wrapper class where I want to be able to pass in a sequence of `name, values` that will replace current instance attributes.  I'm currently struggling to get it to change these instance attributes.  Here is my code:

```
def __repr__(self):
        return ('Table: {table}\nManifest URL: {manifest}\nUnload URL: '
                '{unload}\nS3 Credentials: {s3_creds}\nDev DB Credentials: '
                '{dev_db}\nProd DB Credentials: {prod_db}\nSafe Load: '
                '{safe_load}\nTruncate: {truncate}'.format(
            table=self._table_name,
            manifest=self._manifest_url,
            unload=self._unload_url,
            s3_creds=self._s3_credentials,
            dev_db=self._dev_db_credentials,
            prod_db=self._prod_db_credentials,
            safe_load=self._safe_load,
            truncate=self._truncate
        ))


class RedshiftLoads(RedshiftBase):
    def change_attrs(self, new_attributes):
        """
        Changes the instance attributes.

        :param new_attributes: A sequence (or sequence of sequences) that
        contains the name and new values (name, new_value)

        :return: None
        """

        valid_attribute_names = {
            'table_name': '_table_name',
            'manifest_url': '_manifest_url',
            'unload_url': '_unload_url',
            's3_credentials': '_s3_credentials',
            'dev_db_credentials': '_dev_db_credentials',
            'prod_db_credentials': '_prod_db_credentials',
            'safe_load': '_safe_load',
            'truncate': '_truncate'
        }
        for attr_name, new_val in new_attributes:
        if attr_name not in valid_attribute_names:
            raise ValueError('Must be one of the following values: '
                             '{attrs}'.format(
                attrs=valid_attribute_names.keys()))
        else:
            self_method = valid_attribute_names.get(attr_name)
            print(attr_name)
            print(self_method)
            self.self_method = new_val
```

Here's how I'm testing it:

```
In[3]: rs = aws.RedshiftLoads('s3_creds', 'db_creds')
In[4]: rs.change_attrs((('table_name', 'Test Table'), ('safe_load', True)))
table_name
_table_name
safe_load
_safe_load
In[5]: print(rs)
Table: None
Manifest URL: None
Unload URL: None
S3 Credentials: s3_creds
Dev DB Credentials: None
Prod DB Credentials: db_creds
Safe Load: False
Truncate: False
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting an attribute by the name `self_method`:

```
self.self_method = new_val
```

This is the same attribute, over and over again. It otherwise has no relationship to the value in the `self_method` local variable.

To dynamically set an attribute, use the [`setattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(self, self_method, new_val)
```

This takes the value of `self_method` and sets an attribute by that name on `self` with the value `new_value`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but could you explain how I could simulate this behavior with my code without using `setattr`?  I've tried putting the `self._table_name` as the value in the `valid_attribute_names` `dict`, and it didn't seem to do it either.